# JavaScript enable rules for custom ribbon buttons and Dynamics 365 Mobile Application

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics365-app-mobile

I was wondering are there any known issues regarding Dynamics CRM/365 Mobile App and Custom JavaScript Ribbon enable rules?

My situation:

1. I have custom ribbon button defined as a part of Ribbon XML diff.
2. When I have no related enable rules defined – my custom button is visible in both Web and Mobile interface.
3. If I add the following custom JavaScript enable rule:

   function EnableMyButton() {
       return true; 
   }

a.  For Web Client – button is presented (which is ok)

b.  For Mobile App – it is not visible (which is not ok :()

I have no other scripts attached to my entity form. I’ve the same problem inside Windows Phone and iPad Dynamics 365 apps.

Above mentioned example is very simple; however, I have problem with all the custom JavaScript enable rules inside my CRM instance (Dynamics 365 Online). If I have any custom enable rule attached – custom buttons are just not presented inside mobile application.

Any ideas?